# How to find out what is causing hang

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

My phone (Huawei P8) is hanging. It is hanging when it's not "in use" (at least, not by me or anyone else).

When it hangs, I have to hold down the power button for 10 seconds. When it restarts it works fine. I can single press the power button to put it to standby and return from this state as expected.

I then leave the phone for an amount of time (10 minutes, 30 minutes... whatever it is) and when I return, it has hung.

It still shows the lock screen when I single press the power button.

How can I find out which app(s) or hardware is causing the issue?

Comment: Does the device exhibit same symptoms when booted into safe mode and put to sleep?

Comment: I didn't try this, but I will do

Answer (score 0):

Keep using the device as there is a good chance you'll see a notification that a given app has stopped responding. This will then give you the opportunity to configure/update/uninstall etc

Comment: Whilst this is what I did to fix my issue, I don't think this is a good answer generally for the majority of users. As such, I won't be marking my own answer as answer and would hope another post will explain a way regarding log files or similar. I leave it here in case it is useful to others